# show hide data on load and check/uncheck of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running a script where I need to check if the value of checkbox is checked or not, and then run the jQuery code for hide and doing a show based upon specific checked value. I am not able to fix it.

Trying with this code

```
$(".choosezoho").click(function() {
    var checkValue = $("input[type='radio']").is(':checked');
        alert(checkValue);
});
```

This gives me true on which checkbox I check

This is my html

```
<div class="selectbox_radio">
<blockquote>
    <div title="128167215">Training</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" value="12817215~Training">
</blockquote>   
<input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" checked value="12817215">Use Existing
<input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" value="12817215">Create New

<br/>
<small>If You Check "Choose New" Please Choose a New Contact from below List</small>
<br/>
</div>
<div class="selectbox" style="display:none;">
<select name="customer_name" id="customer_name_select" class="selectItemsLists">
      <option></option>
</select>
</div>
```

and what I am trying is: if the checkbox is choose new, it should load the select box and hide the above and vice versa in other case.

Also it should check what is the initial selection and based upon that trigger in the jQuery code.

Comment: Why value of both radio button is same? To identify which radio button is checked we have to use different values for both radio buttons. So is there any special purpose behind giving same name?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but your use of un-closed inputs, the `small` element and inline styles make me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below snippet.

To achieve this I have changed the values of radio buttons to identify and show/hide accordingly.

And the existing and new customer HTML is wrapped with ids so we can make show/hide accordingly.

```js
$(".choosezoho").on('change',function() {
  var checkValue = $('input[name=usethisexisting]:checked').val()
  if(checkValue=="new"){
    $("#existingCustomer").hide();
    $("#newCustomer").show();
  }else{
    $("#existingCustomer").show();
    $("#newCustomer").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectbox_radio">
  <blockquote id="existingCustomer">
    <div title="128167215">Training</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" value="12817215~Training">
  </blockquote>   
  <input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" checked value="existing">Use Existing
  <input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" value="new">Create New

  <br/>
  <div id="newCustomer" style='display:none;'>
    <small>If You Check "Choose New" Please Choose a New Contact from below List</small>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="selectbox" style="display:none;">
    <select name="customer_name" id="customer_name_select" class="selectItemsLists">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$(".choosezoho").change()` instead of click and than use `$(this)` to see if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".choosezoho").on('change',function() {
  var checkValue = $('input[name=usethisexisting]:checked').val()
  if(checkValue=="new"){
    $("#existingCustomer").hide();
    $("#newCustomer").show();
    $('.selectbox').show();
  }else{
    $("#existingCustomer").show();
    $("#newCustomer").hide();
    $('.selectbox').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="selectbox_radio">
  <blockquote id="existingCustomer">
    <div title="128167215">Training</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" value="12817215~Training">
  </blockquote>   
  <input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" checked value="existing">Use Existing
  <input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" value="new">Create New

  <br/>
  <div id="newCustomer" style='display:none;'>
    <small>If You Check "Choose New" Please Choose a New Contact from below List</small>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="selectbox" style="display:none;">
    <select name="customer_name" id="customer_name_select" class="selectItemsLists">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: hope you are looking for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You should give each of your radio inputs a unique id, and then put them in a div. That way you can show / hide the entire div.

Then you can bind a change event to the Create New radio input and see if it is checked, if so you can show the select box and hide the radio fields.

```
$("#createNewID").bind("change",function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
          $('.selectbox').show();
          $('#radioInput').hide();
}
```

See JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1h2xaL5x/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".choosezoho").on('change',function() {
  var checkValue = $('input[name=usethisexisting]:checked').val()
  if(checkValue=="new"){
    $("#existingCustomer").hide();
    $("#newCustomer").show();
    $('.selectbox').show();
  }else{
    $("#existingCustomer").show();
    $("#newCustomer").hide();
    $('.selectbox').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectbox_radio">
  <blockquote id="existingCustomer">
    <div title="128167215">Training</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" value="12817215~Training">
  </blockquote>   
  <input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" checked value="existing">Use Existing
  <input type="radio" class="choosezoho" name="usethisexisting" value="new">Create New

  <br/>
  <div id="newCustomer" style='display:none;'>
    <small>If You Check "Choose New" Please Choose a New Contact from below List</small>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="selectbox" style="display:none;">
    <select name="customer_name" id="customer_name_select" class="selectItemsLists">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Now it is updated

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not very different from previous ones, however, it shows some small details that seem useful to me. The switch allows widespread use for more cases and makes things clearer.

I understand that the "input type text" must also be shown in the "Select New" option, the list appears in the other case. Right?

There are also minor changes in html.

```js
        $(".choosezoho").bind("change",function() {
             if($(this).is(':checked')){
                 switch( $(this).attr('id') ) {
                     case "createNew":
                         $('#nameSelect1').hide();
                         $('#newCustomerDiv').show();
                         break;
                     case "useExisting":
                         $('#nameSelect1').show();
                         $('#newCustomerDiv').hide();
                         break;
                 }
             }
         });

     //setDefault
     $('#useExisting').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectbox_radio" >
      <blockquote>
        <div title="128167215"
             id="trainingID">
          Training
        </div>
        <div id="newCustomerDiv">
        <label for="customerName">New customer name:</label>
        <input type="input"
               id="customerName"
               name="customer_name"
               id="customer_name"
               value="12817215~Training">
        </div>
      </blockquote>
      <input type="radio"
             id = "useExisting"
             class="choosezoho"
             name="usethisexisting"
             checked value="12817215">
      Use Existing
      <input type="radio"
             id="createNew"
             class="choosezoho"
             name="usethisexisting"
             value="12817215">
      Create New
      <br/>
      <small>If You Check "Choose New" Please Choose a New
        Contact from below List</small>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="nameSelect1" class="selectbox" style="display:none;">
      <select name="customer_name" id="customer_name_select"
              class="selectItemsLists">
        <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
        <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```